# How can I force Spark to keep each (key, Array[T]) on a different partition?

Tags: java, scala, hadoop, apache-spark, hadoop-yarn

I have an RDD with key value pairs, where values are arrays of a type. I would like for each such key (keys are uniques here) value pair to be on a separate partition, so that Yarn can properly schedule tasks on different nodes with proper load balancing. How can I force Spark to do so. I can use **repartition**, but that is not solving my problem. I can still see 2 key value pairs on some partititions even when the number of partitions I set is more than the number of key value pairs.

Comment: partitionBy(new HashPartitioner(100)). You can create own HashPartitioner with desired properties.

Comment: Can you give some example. In this case, I want to create partitions using the key in (key, Array[T]). Each key is unique.

Comment: @MetallicPriest take a look on different partition strategies in (comments will explain everything in details):  graphX:https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/0a4071eab30db1db80f61ed2cb2e7243291183ce/graphx/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/graphx/PartitionStrategy.scala#L32

Comment: With regards to spark API you must create own partitioner that realize abstract class [Partitioner](https://spark.apache.org/docs/1.4.1/api/scala/index.html#org.apache.spark.Partitioner). There are only two methods: def
getPartition(key: Any): Int and def
numPartitions: Int. Make your getPartition to return unique values for every key (increment private field). 
One remark: max limit is 2^31+1 (max possitive Int).

Comment: @ipoteka Is it work with RDD partitioning? I see that PartitionStrategy is located in GraphX library.

Comment: @Zernike I provided this link as example of advanced partition usage. Your comments are provide enough information for full answer, as i think.